# Recurring Payment Processing and Merchant Account Solutions (primarily Asia)

Tags: payment, payment-processing, recurring-billing

In your experience which are the best recurring payment solution and merchant account providers in Asia?

What would you think are the key criteria to choose a recurring billing solutions provider? (with most Asian currencies)

Based on what I found in my search so far, I noted the following.

1. PayPal does provide recurring payment services in Asia - but customer support is as bad as it is elsewhere with PayPal around the world and with the additional risk of getting blocked for >5% of refunds.
2. PCI Compliance is absolutely necessary on the part of provider.
3. Based on initial search found "Money Bookers" but not sure how good their service is - seem to be able to transact in 200 countries so far.

Your experiences (good experiences & warnings) in dealing with recurring billing providers and merchant accounts will be helpful to choose for my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

TechCrunch recently featured SaaSy which seems to fit your criteria pretty well: http://techcrunch.com/2011/03/17/online-subscription-billing-is-still-a-hassle-saasy-aims-to-change-that/

Comment: Thanks! It does seem to have some good feature set with added advantage of them dealing with money on their own (expanding their parent companies capability). However, I am looking for solutions that specifically deal with asian currencies / payment gateways also. Any pointers will be helpful.